# Titanium - Error Loading Browser - MOZILLA_HOME_FIVE not set

Tags: eclipse, browser, widget, titanium, mozilla

Firstly, I am running on Manjaro Linux.

I downloaded Titanium, unzipped it, then ran it. All fine. However, at startup it is throwing a "Cannot find chromimum. See documentation for possible workaround/fixes" error which is then followed by a MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set error and lastly it suggests that I should terminate the workbench due to a SWT Error.

I've tried the many suggestions I've found online including:

- Installing xulrunner. Did not work.
- Setting an env variable called MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME according to (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinuxrcp). However, I may have messeg up following these instructions. If anyone would kindly explain what step number 2 means with a little bit of extra detail, I would seriously appreciate it.

I will post the full error I am getting below:

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1826)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.(Browser.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.(BrowserViewer.java:225)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.BrowserViewerWrapper.createSWTBrowserViewer(BrowserViewerWrapper.java:26)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.browser.AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.createBrowserViewer(AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.java:211)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.browser.AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.createPartControl(AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2942)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.Portal$1.runInUIThread(Portal.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

Comment: installing titanium via yaourt -S titanium-studio. There are a couple of extra dependencies that may solve this problem. Will repost if this solution works for fellow arch-linuxers.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install Titatinum through yaourt, it still did not work, however, it did install a couple of dependencies that I had not yet considered. So basically this is the solution:

Make sure you have the following dependencies before initializing Titanium Studio:

titanium-studio dependencies:
 - java-environment>=6 (already installed)
 - gtk2>=2.20 (already installed)
 - webkitgtk2 (already installed)
 - libpng12 (already installed)
 - libjpeg6 (already installed)
 - nodejs (already installed)
 - sudo (already installed)
 - findutils (already installed)